# If AB is a projection then BA is a projection

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given two complex matrices $A$ and $B$, and knowing $AB$ is a projection, prove or provide a counterexample that $BA$ is a projection.
Stuck with this question, need help.
According to the matrix projection properties, $BA$ should be idempotent to be projection, so $(BA)(BA)$ = $BA$. We can rewrite it, if $B$ is invertible, as

> $$(BA)(BA)=B(AB)(AB)B^{-1} \Rightarrow (BA)(BA)=BA.$$

However it seems impossible in given conditions to prove that $B$ is invertible, so I am most likely moving in the wrong direction.
Any help or reference much is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: If $B = A^\ast$, at least, then you are indeed in business. Without some sort of additional hypothesis on $A$ or $B$, though, user7530's answer provides a counterexample.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not true.

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}0 &0\\0 &1\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc}0 &1\\0 &0\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}0 &0\\0 &0\end{array}\right]$$
is a projection but

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}0 &1\\0 &0\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc}0 &0\\0 &1\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{cc}0 &1\\0 &0\end{array}\right]$$

is not.